# Magento Upgrade (2.4.3-p1 >> 2.4.4) Compilation Error

Tags: upgrade, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.4

I am upgrading our current site from 2.4.3-p1 to 2.4.4. I had to apply multiple patches for upgrading. However, while running di:compile, its give me error as below

```
MiBInterface "Magento\GraphQl\Helper\Error\ExceptionMessageFormatterInterface" not found#0 /var/www/magento/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(571): include()
#1 /var/www/magento/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(428): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/var/www/magent...')
#2 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Magento\\Payment...')
#3 /var/www/magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(134): class_exists('Magento\\Payment...')
#4 /var/www/magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(117): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->includeClass('Magento\\Payment...', '/var/www/magent...')
#5 /var/www/magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php(87): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->extract(Object(RecursiveIteratorIterator))
#6 /var/www/magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/RepositoryGenerator.php(61): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->getList('/var/www/magent...')
#7 /var/www/magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php(56): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\RepositoryGenerator->doOperation()
#8 /var/www/magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php(216): Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process(Object(Closure), Object(Closure))
#9 /var/www/magento/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#10 /var/www/magento/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1009): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#11 /var/www/magento/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#12 /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(115): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#13 /var/www/magento/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#14 /var/www/magento/bin/magento(23): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#15 {main}
```

When I check the module mentioned in error ie: Magento\GraphQl\Helper, I see it has been removed from 2.4.4 and in my composer.json, the module is already under replace.

However, couple of classes still uses it. If I remove this entry, other error comes. I am unsure how to overcome/resolve this.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Having the same issue with the same error, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

[`Magento\GraphQl\Helper\Error\ExceptionMessageFormatterInterface`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.4/app/code/Magento/GraphQl/Helper/Error/ExceptionMessageFormatterInterface.php) seems to be new in Magento 2.4.4. It is used by the module itself, but also by other GraphQL modules (search for ["implements ExceptionMessageFormatterInterface"](https://github.com/magento/magento2/search?q=%22implements+ExceptionMessageFormatterInterface%22)).

If I understand your question correctly, then you have disabled the module in the `composer.json` using a `replace` property to replace it with `*` (like is done in the [`yireo/magento2-replace-graphql` module](https://github.com/yireo/magento2-replace-graphql/blob/magento-2.4/composer.json#L35) module). I would suggest to remove this (and probably other) `replace` entries and properly install the module using Composer to get back the behaviour as intended by Magento.

BTW I have used the Composer `replace` trick in the past, but stopped using it, as it introduced to many errors. If I really want to disable a module, I do this via `app/etc/config.php`.